# How to speed up Pandas contains when moving rows to another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a small script which checks for a condition and if true moves the pandas dataframe row to a new dataframe and then removes the row from the original dataframe.

Originally, I was doing with this regex but this was slow and after some reading on SO I tried it this way - it's slightly quicker.

The production data I'm using runs this across millions of rows so any time saved will be a big help.

Anything I can do to optimise it further?

```
import pandas as pd


data = [['thomas cook', 222], ['holidays', 333], ['cheap flights', 444], ['thomascook holidays', 555]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['query', 'clicks'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=df1.columns)

print(df1)
                 query  clicks
0          thomas cook     222
1             holidays     333
2        cheap flights     444
3  thomascook holidays     555

brand_terms = ['thomas cook', 'thomascook', 'thomas-cook']
for brand_term in brand_terms:
    condtion = df1[df1["query"].str.contains(brand_term, case=False, regex=False)]
    df2 = df2.append(condtion, ignore_index=True)
    df1.drop(condtion.index, inplace=True)

print(df1)
           query  clicks
1       holidays     333
2  cheap flights     444


print(df2)
                 query clicks
0          thomas cook    222
1  thomascook holidays    555
```

Comment: if you have lots of duplicates within your data, you could convert the `query` column to a categorical dtype before filtering; should notice significant improvement. Or Create a mapping(a unique dataframe), and filter the larger one with it. Both ways would involve using @anuragdabas solution

Comment: there will be some duplication but nothing major - I'll give it a got regardless :)

Comment: So this made it slower but from the updates below, I'd got it to around 1:30 consistently. However, I applied your suggestion to another column with lots of duplication and the script just finished in 39 seconds :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str.contains()` and don't change `regex` parameter:

```
df2=(df1.loc[df1["query"].str.contains(pat='|'.join(brand_terms), case=False)]
        .reset_index(drop=True))
```

output of df2:

```
    query                   clicks
0   thomas cook             222
1   thomascook holidays     555
```

**Update:**

You can use `~`(the bitwise negation operator) for that(for example):

```
df1=(df1.loc[~df1["query"].str.contains(pat='|'.join(brand_terms), case=False)])
        .reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Note:**

store your condition in a variable for simplicity and performance:

```
m=df1["query"].str.contains(pat='|'.join(brand_terms), case=False)
df1=df1.loc[~m].reset_index(drop=True)
df2=df1.loc[m].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: how would I then remove the rows from df1?

Comment: @Adders updated answer...kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: thanks - your solution takes my test case of about 4k rows from 2:51 seconds to 2:37 seconds. Any other suggestions? :)

Comment: @Adders store your condition in a variable that will be more efficient and fast..kindly check the note part in the answer **:)**

Comment: so this actually triggered a thought for another part of my code which has just taken a full minute off the runtime (1:38 seconds!) Absolutely amazing

Answer (score 0):

Try using Modin. It will surely improve performance with just one line of code.Modin accelerates Pandas queries by 4x.

```
import modin.pandas as pd
```

Here is an article to get started: https://www.kdnuggets.com/2019/11/speed-up-pandas-4x.html`

Comment: Thanks, it says this is experimental so something I'll maybe look at in the future

Answer (score 0):

1. Try [Vaex](https://vaex.io/docs/index.html), as an alternative to pandas which the internet says is faster than pandas for string operations.
2. Other option that you can try is do a set_index on query. I don't know the nature of your query column so can't really tell if this will help. If your query falls in a defined set, setting it as index will reduce rows to check and access that index can get you all rows
3. Also you can change your regex to $'thomas\s?-?cook'^ and check